# Can my code be classified as a depth first search?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I wrote code for a DFS after reading about what it is but not actually seeing the code. I did this to challenge myself (I always have believed that to learn something new you must always first challenge yourself). The thing is after I wrote my code, I compared my implementation to the one in the book I read it in (Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms - A. Levitin) and it is completely different. So now I am wondering well it works as intended... is it still a DFS?

I made the implementation to solve a maze. I will give a rundown on my code and also upload the code here (Some people hate reading other people's code while others do.)

Algorithm (What I understood and did):

1. Convert maze into a graph/map
2. Set start position as current node and run loop in which...
3. I choose one of the adjacent nodes as the next current node and do this until I stumble upon a dead end. Also I am adding each node I pass through into a list that acts as my stack.
4. Once I am at a dead end, I keep poping items from the stack and each time I pop, I check if it has adjacent nodes that have not been visited.
5. Once I have found an unvisited adjacent node, we continue the entire process from step 3.
6. We do this until current node is the end position.
7. Then I just retrace my way back through the stack.

Here is my code:

```
# Depth First Search implementation for maze...

# from random import choice
from copy import deepcopy
import maze_builderV2 as mb

order = 10
space = ['X']+['_' for x in range(order)]+['X']
maze = [deepcopy(space) for x in range(order)]
maze.append(['X' for x in range(order+2)])
maze.insert(0, ['X' for x in range(order+2)])

finalpos = (order, order)

pos = (1, 1)

maze[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 'S'  # Initializing a start position
maze[finalpos[0]][finalpos[1]] = 'O'  # Initializing a end position

mb.mazebuilder(maze=maze)


def spit():
    for x in maze:
        print(x)

spit()
print()

mazemap = {}

def scan():  # Converts raw map/maze into a suitable datastructure.
    for x in range(1, order+1):
        for y in range(1, order+1):
            mazemap[(x, y)] = []
            t = [(x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x, y-1), (x, y+1)]
            for z in t:
                if maze[z[0]][z[1]] == 'X':
                    pass
                else:
                    mazemap[(x, y)].append(z) 

scan()

path = [pos] # stack
impossible = False

while path[-1] != finalpos:
    curpos = path[-1]
    i = 0
    while i < len(mazemap[curpos]):
        if mazemap[curpos][i] in path:
            del mazemap[curpos][i]
        else:
            i += 1
    nextpos = None
    if mazemap[curpos] == []:
        while nextpos == None:
            try:
                wrongpos = path.pop(-1)
                if mazemap[wrongpos] == []:
                    pass
                else:
                    path.append(wrongpos)
                    # nextpos = choice(mazemap[wrongpos])
                    nextpos = mazemap[wrongpos][-1]
                    mazemap[wrongpos].remove(nextpos)
            except IndexError:
                impossible = True
                break
    else:
        # nextpos = choice(mazemap[curpos])
        nextpos = mazemap[curpos][-1]
    if impossible:
        break
    path.append(nextpos)

if not impossible:
    for x in path:
            if x == pos or x == finalpos:
                pass
            else:
                maze[x[0]][x[1]] = 'W'
else:
    print("This maze not solvable, Blyat!")
    print()

spit()
```

As always, I greatly appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: A concern is you use a single stack to keep track of nodes which have been visited and nodes which are being considered.  If a node becomes a dead end won't it be removed from the stack?  But, what keeps it from being visited again after its removed (i.e. using a different path)?  Compare to [this](https://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/) which uses two separate lists: 1) set of visited nodes, and 2) stack (list) of current nodes.  An advantage of using a set is its much faster to check if you have visited a node than a list.

Comment: Okay I think may not have put one thing, but I keep getting rid of it in my adjacency list that is my maze map/graph. That is as I pop an element, I check its adjacent nodes and if those nodes are already visited, I remove from my map/graph, because I know for sure now that it wont be useful anymore...

Comment: Another concern is `while path[-1] != finalpos:`.  What happens when there is no path through the maze (i.e. can't arrive at finalpos)?

Comment: Try and except clause exists for that

Comment: @Prithvidiamond--the normal solution for this is to run until either the stack is empty or you reach the goal. Using Try and except is unusual for this.

Comment: @DarrylG It is the same thing, once the stack is empty, if it pops, it will give index error and I have tried to except that, that is handle the situation.

Comment: That sounds like a DFS to me.  But if your maze has cycles, you may have a problem.

Comment: @btilly Could you explain further about what you are trying to say?

Comment: Another issue is the while loop `while i < len(mazemap[curpos]):` It's frequently error prone to delete elements in a list by index while iterating over it.

Comment: @Prithvidiamond Set up a maze with a big empty room down a wrong path that your program will try first.  You may be surprised at how long your algorithm can get stuck finding ways to wander around in that big empty room.

Comment: @DarrylG It wont, because it does not change i when element has been deleted

Comment: @btilly I already know it isnt the most efficient implementation, any suggestions to make it more efficient?

Comment: @Prithvidiamond Use a Python `set` object to keep track of what positions you have ever visited.  Checking it will be a `O(1)` operation, and it won't be tied to the path that you are currently visiting.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm looks DFS to me. DFS means exploring the path as deep as possible,  backtrack to the previous node only if there is no solution and your algorithm works in a similar way by popping nodes from the stack. You just mimic the recursion stack using your own stack so it looks quite different from the standard solution.

Essentially, all recursive algorithms can be simulated using stack and loop. But most of the time doing this will make the algorithm much less readable. To tackle a difficult problem, I think the usual way to do it is to first come up with the recursive solution. After making sure the recursive solution is bug-free, then start implementing the iterative version using stack if you care a lot about the efficiency.

Other Suggestion:

- **if mazemap[curpos][i] in path:** is a O(n) operation since path is a normal list. Consider using a separate hash set to store visited nodes and use the set to check repetition instead to make it O(1).

Comment: Thanks so much! I am glad I was able to get the solution to work without actually having to look for a solution in the book or on the internet. I will implement your suggestions and then tackle BFS in a similar mannar!

Comment: Ok I was having some trouble trying understand what you said about reducing my O(n) operation to O(1). 
Could you explain a bit more in detail?

Comment: **if mazemap[curpos][i] in path** takes O(n) time where n is the length of the path; If you create something like **pathSet = set()** at the beginning then **if mazemap[curpos][i] in pathSet** takes O(1) time. Of course when you add / delete something from path, you need to add / delete that from pathSet as well. Add/delete from set only takes O(1) time so it will not lower the whole time complexity.

Comment: Okay, so is it worth the trouble of changing it to a set? Will the performance difference be noticable or negligible?

Comment: Assume the total number of nodes is N, in some cases you have to visit all N nodes to find out the path, then for each node you algorithm is executing **if mazemap[curpos][i] in path:** 4 times. Since the path size can also be N in the worst case so essentially your algorithm will become **O(N*4*N) = O(N^2)**. Using set will lower the whole algorithm to be **O(N)**. I would say it is a significant improvement and worth the effort.

Comment: Ok now it makes sense! Thanks you so much!